# register allocation on iterative cycles

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to implement an idea where part of the register is incrementally taken, shift left twice and subtract one from the residue. Following is the piece of code I am working on. I am required to take Bplusone[0] in the first iteration, shift it left twice and subtract 1'b1 from it, then have zeros in the remaining part of the register. Then take Bplusone[1:0] on the next iteration, shift left twice, subtract 1'b1 and have zeros filling up the remaining part of the register. I am stuck here.

Here's what I have done:
I initialized the registers A, B and iteration count using Reset. Then used MUXs to perform some operation on the registers and had Aplusone and Bplusone as the outputs. Then incrementally take outputs from Aplusone and Bplusone, perform some operation on them, store it in registers F1 and F2 and finally choose from these to get the desired output in the register F. How do I go about with iplementing the process I described above?

```
input logic Clk;
input logic Reset;
input logic [1:0] sjplusone;
output logic [11:0] F;
output logic [7:0] Aplusone;

logic [7:0] K, A, B, Bplusone;
logic [9:0] F1, F2;
logic Kout;
integer iterator;

always @(posedge Clk) begin
    if(Reset) begin
        iterator = 1'b0;
        A = 8'b00000000;
        B = 8'b00000000; end
    else 
        F1 = ~Aplusone << 9 - iterator;
        F2 =  (Bplusone << 9 - iterator) -1'b1;
        iterator = iterator + 1;    
    end
    
    shiftreg #(8) shr (Clk, Reset, Load, 1'b1, 8'b11111111, K, Kout);
    mux2 #(8) m1 ({A[6:0], Kout}, {B[6:0], ~Kout}, sjplusone[1], Aplusone);
    mux2 #(8) m2 ({B[6:0], Kout}, {A[6:0], ~Kout}, ~sjplusone[1], Bplusone);
    mux2 #(12) Fmux ({2'b11, F1},   {2'b00, F2}, sjplusone[1], F);
```

Comment: ammrra, It is not clear to me what you are trying to do here. Some questions: - Is this something that you want to be synthesizable (implemented in hardware)? - Does this need to function continuously? (Is there a stream of data to process?) - This doesn't seem like the sort of thing where structural verilog would be required, and it doesn't help make the example clearer. (mux2, for example, is a simple function easily implemented in behavioral code). - Some sort of example with actual values might help us better understand. - A higher-level description of what you are trying to do may also he

Comment: Yes, I want this to be synthesizable. This is only a part of what I am trying to do. I want to instantiate this entire module elsewhere. There are about 8 iterations in this. And I want part of a register to be extracted incrementally with each iteration. And then extracted part is manipulated(e.g. one's complement in one case, subtracting 1'b1 in another case) which I implemented in the always block. The rest(structural) is the implementation of other functions that I want to incorporate in this block. I am stuck with the implementation of always block. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, so I am posting another answer.

Is there an end to the process?  I mean you incrementally pick off and process bits from 1 to 8 (I assume).
When you get to 8, what happens on the next clock cycle, start over?

Here is an example, showing only F2, doing what I think you are trying to do (although I am not sure what should happen after reaching the 8th iteration.)  It is possible, I am sure, to write this more elegantly.

```
always @(posedge Clk or posedge Reset) begin
    if(Reset) begin
        iterator <= 1'b0;
        A        <= 8'b00000000;
        B        <= 8'b00000000; 
    end
    else begin
        case (iterator)
        0: F2 <= (Bplusone[0]   << 2) - 9'd1;
        1: F2 <= (Bplusone[1:0] << 2) - 9'd1;
        2: F2 <= (Bplusone[2:0] << 2) - 9'd1;
        3: F2 <= (Bplusone[3:0] << 2) - 9'd1;
        4: F2 <= (Bplusone[4:0] << 2) - 9'd1;
        5: F2 <= (Bplusone[5:0] << 2) - 9'd1;
        6: F2 <= (Bplusone[6:0] << 2) - 9'd1;
        7: F2 <= (Bplusone[7:0] << 2) - 9'd1;
        endcase

        if (iterator >= 7) iterator <= 0;  // Reset iterator after 8th iteration
        else               iterator <= iterator + 1;    
    end
```